# Using Solspace's Importer, how to update Structure-managed listings?

Tags: structure

I have been trying to import 3k+ entries using the Solspace Importer, and each entry is being imported into a channel managed by Structure as listings. When I try to manually edit one of these imported entries, the Structure URL field is blank until I save it. Is there a way to have the Structure URL updated for all these entries without having to manually save each one?

Comment: I know this was a while ago but curious if you ever found a work around for this :)

Comment: Unfortunately I did not, I ended up using a channel workaround without Structure.

Comment: Yeah I'm afraid I might need to do that too! :/ I ended up re-saving each entry but might be an issue in the future. Structure is great as long as you're never planning on using any sort of Importing :( Thanks for the reply mate! Cheers.